# Why are my emails getting queued?

Tags: cron

When purchasing something the order goes through on the website the money gets removed from my account but I don't get an email confirmation to confirm my purchase, but I get other emails like wishlist suggestions newsletter etc not at the same time but it seems to be just sales emails.

I recently install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html extention to see what cron jobs I have running on my site.

[image]

Why is my core_email_queue_send_all so packed and how do I clean it out ?

Once I selected all my cron jobs and clicked run my sales emails started coming through, I thought this would run automatically but apparently not, any ideas on how to make this run automatically ?

Comment: Did you check your crontab? Are other crons actually running?

Comment: Everything says enabled but no according to the timeline view there not actually running, I don't know why I saw somewhere that the corn.php file maybe have been altered so I replaced it with the original i got from the theme and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure there is a crontab actually running? That's something you need to configure on your server, not in Magento

Comment: Well there are no cron jobs listed in my server cpanel, is it the cron.php file that needs to be run every 5 mins ?

Comment: Yes, actually the `cron.sh` file. You'll need something like `*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh <your_directory>/cron.sh` in your crontab

Comment: Ok I've added it to the cron jobs in the cpanel /home/cutpric5/public_html/cron.sh so that should now solve the email problems pretty much.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: No emails are still not being sent out. Still says I have like 20 emails to be queued for sending.

Comment: And are any other crons now running?

Comment: Well no i used cron doctor from the magento extension store and deleted all pending cron jobs to start a fresh and still for some reason the heartbeat isn't running every 5 mins.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the AOE Scheduler, that module works flawlessly on all our installations, so no need to install CronDoctor or any other cron managing module. I bet there's something wrong with your crontab, maybe you should contact your hosting provider.

Comment: My hosting provided stated that my cron.sh fil wasnt executable so he changed it to 744 to hopefully fix the problem

Comment: Any updates on this? Were permissions your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this after looking at another article since the update to 1.9.1 magento has moved the job of sending emails to a cron job, now since for some reason my cron jobs aren't working as they should I viewed an article which says you need to remove or comment out line #76 in “Mailer.php" - app/code/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php #76 to stop the emails being added to the cron job and have it send using the original way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cron email order queue is a 1.9.1 feature.  I think you've got a different issue.